# Colorbox: Show/simulate 'loading' animation for inline content

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Hi there I'm using ColorBox, and we do few steps in a form with jquery, and we want to show the loading animation of ColorBox while we are waiting for the reply from ajax.

How we can use it?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 6):

You can turn the loading graphic on and off with the calls:

```
$('#cboxLoadingGraphic').show();
```

and

```
$('#cboxLoadingGraphic').hide();
```

In my app I call the show method in the beginning of the function call, then the hide method when the ajax call returns.

Comment: I had to call $("#cboxLoadingOverlay").show(); instead of $('#cboxLoadingGraphic').show();

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want is fastIframe

```
$("#thediv").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:870, innerHeight:500, fastIframe:false});
```